# Selenium, Python. Gives no such element: Unable to locate element error whether the button is there

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

I am working on my test case which includes sending values to the input fields for buying tickets. But for this case selenium gives me unable to locate element error while I am trying to locate input field named itemq_3728, the problem is the page is changing the name of input field every time it reopens the page.

How can I locate the input field ?
 I try the XPath but can't achieve the goal and also couldn't write it relative to the name of the ticket

```
<table id="bms_tickets" width="90%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" class="bms_tickets table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th width="240px">PRICE</th>

                    <th width="100px">QUANTITY</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="resTypesTable">


<tr id="bms_restype_3728" class="bms_restype">
<td class="bms_restype_desc">
    Gen Ad


    <div style="font-size:10px;margin-left:5px;">

    </div>
</td>                       
<td class="bms_restype_price">


            $10.00
            <input type="hidden" name="pay_itemq_3728" value="10.00">   



</td>

<td class="bms_restype_qty">    

                <input type="text" name="itemq_3728" value="0" placeholder="1" min="1">
</td>

</tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help assuming only numeric path of name changes after pageload:
'`//td[@class="bms_restype_qty"]//input[starts-­‐with(@name,"itemq")]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can locate it using `cssSelector` as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td.bms_restype_qty > input[type='text']")
```

Or if you're interested to locate this element using `xpath` you can locate it wrt `Gen Ad` name column text as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[normalize-space(.)='Gen Ad' and @class = 'bms_restype_desc']/following-sibling::td[@class='bms_restype_qty']/input")
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[td[normalize-space(.)='Gen Ad']]/td[@class='bms_restype_qty']/input")
```